# How to calculate $\oint\frac{dz}{z^3(z+4)}$ for $|z-2|<3$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, residue-calculus

Which is right

$$\oint\frac{dz}{z^3(z+4)}=2\pi i(\text{Res}(f,0)+\text{Res}(f,-4))$$

or

$$\oint\frac{dz}{z^3(z+4)}=2\pi i\,\text{Res}(f,0)$$?

I am unsure because $z=-4$ is outside $|z-2|<3$ so does its Residue included in the value of the integral?

Comment: The second one is right. You only care about the poles inside your contour.

Comment: Recall residue theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second is right !!!. Namely,
$\displaystyle 2\pi\,\mathrm{i}\,{1 \over 2!}\,\lim_{z \to 0}{\mathrm{d}^{2} \over \mathrm{d}z^{2}}\left[z^{3}\,{1 \over z^{3}\left(z + 4\right)}\right] =
\pi\,\mathrm{i}\,\lim_{z \to 0}{2 \over \left(z + 4\right)^{3}} =
\bbox[5px,border:1px dotted navy]{\displaystyle{\pi \over 32}\,\mathrm{i}}$